# How long does it take for a map area to reset?

Tags: path-of-exile

When I leave a map (like *Ancient Pyramid*, *Fetid Pool*, *Tidal Island*...) through a town portal, entrance, or teleporter and immediately return to it, the map stays explored.

But, if I don't return for about half an hour in singleplayer (without a party), I have to start over with exploring the map.

**How long can I stay outside a map without losing my exploration progress?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can stay between 8 and 15 minutes outside an instance before it reset:

[Poe wiki](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Diablo_Player's_Guide_to_Path_of_Exile) :

> "All areas in Path of Exile are instanced. When you enter an area, a new instance is created. Once you leave the area, the instance will remain in its current state for 15 minutes for main areas - if 15 minutes passes with no players entering the instance, it will be closed. Entering the same area again will create a new instance with a new randomly generated map. Areas without side areas attached (any area with two or less exits) has a shorter timer, and will only last 8 minutes while empty."

In addition, you can open the Instance Manager menu with 'CTRL + Left Click' on an entrance (or portal) that will show you exactly the time left after the reset of the instance.

It looks like this (patch 2.2.0):
[image: Instance Manager]

It is mainly use to reset manually an instance for farming a specific area.

Comment: Now that's how you provide evidence. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Between 8 to 15 minutes, if they are empty. They won't reset when there is a player in the instance, and the timer resets when a player entered the instance.

[Source](http://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Diablo_Player%27s_Guide_to_Path_of_Exile#Instances)

I can also add an in-game screenshot from the tips in the loadingscreen if needed.

Answer (score -1):

Maps are Auto resetting after 15min. Have a look [here](https://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/69060), for enter the same instance.

Comment: It's 15 minutes if the area has two or more entrances.  8 minutes if it has just one.

Comment: That source is just a forum where one individual says "Zones aoutoreset after 15 minutes( if i remember it correctly) after u leave them." Can you confirm that from your own experience or corroborate it somewhere else?